# Java - underscore

Tags: java

Don't know if it's a duplicate (couldn't find the words to search like *"java character allowed"*). I had this question on test interview :

---

Consider the following class :

```
class _ {_ f; _(){}_(_ f){_ t = f; f = t;}_(_ f, _ g){}}
```

1. Does this compile ?
2. If yes, what does this code do ?

So my answer was no, but I had wrong. Could someone explain me how does this compile ? (I try on my IDE and I was surprise that yes its compiles fine)

Comment: The real question you should ask yourself is why wouldn't it compile ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underscore character is treated just like a letter in Java, as far as identifiers are concerned.  The [JLS, Section 3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) covers what an identifier can consist of:

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

and

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

So this compiles.  It defines a class called `_`, with a member variable of the same class name `_` called `f`.  There are 3 constructors -- one with no arguments that does nothing, one with one `f` argument of type `_`, and one with two arguments `f` and `g` of type `_` that does nothing.

That second constructor declares a local variable `t` of type `_` and assigns the parameter `f` to it, then assigns `t` back to `f` (it doesn't touch the instance variable `f`).

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers in Java may contain any Unicode character, unless the identifier is neither a keyword or a bool or a null literal. And they should not start with a digit. For details, check out the reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Your example code satisfies these criteria. The code after a little renaming is as follows:

```
class SomeClass
{
    SomeClass f;
    SomeClass() {}
    SomeClass(SomeClass f)
    {
        SomeClass t = f;
        f = t;
    }
    SomeClass(SomeClass f, SomeClass g) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You see it starts with `class _`, so we are declaring a class named (the underscore character).  Perhaps this becomes more sensible if you replace `_` with a word you might use to name a class.

```
class thing {  //we're declaring a class called 'thing'

thing f;  //the class contains a member variable called 'f' that is of type thing

thing(){  //this is the constructor
}

//It was a default constructor, it doesn't do anything else

//Here is another constructor

thing(thing f) {   //This constructor takes a parameter named 'f' of type thing

// We are declaring a local variable 't' of type thing, and assigning the value of f that was passed in when the constructor was called
thing t = f;  

f = t;  //Now we assign the value of t to f, kind of an odd thing to do but it is valid.
}

//Now we have another constructor
thing(thing f, thing g){  //This one takes two parameters of type thing called 'f' and 'g'
}  //And it doesn't do anything with them...

} //end class declaration
```

So in summary, it compiles because it is valid java code as I tried to explain above.

Answer (score 1):

That's really cool!

```
class _ //Underscore is a valid name for a class
{
    _ f; //A reference to another instance of the _ class named f

    _() //The constructor of the _ class
    {
    //It's empty!
    }

    _(_ f) //A second constructor that takes an other instance of _ called f as a parameter
    {    
        _ t = f; // A new reference to a _ object called t that now points to f
        f = t;   // f points to t (which, well, points to f :) )
    }

    _(_ f, _ g) //A third constructor with two parameters this time of _ instances.
    {
        //It's empty!
    }
} // End of class definition!
```